# Ignore case in enum values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created one mongoose schema as below:

```
const quesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
acRate: {
    type: Number,
},
difficulty: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
        values: ['EASY', 'MEDIUM', 'HARD'],
        message: 'Difficulty should be either EASY, MEDIUM or HARD',
    },
},
title: {
    type: String,
},
titleSlug: {
    type: String,
},
topicTags: [
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
],
});
```

In the data, the difficulty may occur in any case. I could not figure out how to ignore the case for the enum easily. I can make a custom validator that will make the input value lowercase/uppercase. But is there any other solution to it?

Comment: A good solution for such situations is to do `toUpperCase()` before saving value so you have consistency it would also make querying it easier.

Comment: @Hussam , thanks for commenting. Yes, it is a good solution. but in my case, I already have a JSON file with more than 10k data, and I am importing all the data at once by using Model.create(). I can push the data one by one using the mentioned solution, but I was wondering if there is any method by which we can ignore the case in the schema itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `lowercase: true` in your schema.

[Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options)